# PyQt4 : With QTabWidget, can I get the "tab-moved" SIGNAL?

Tags: pyqt, tabwidget

I use a `QTabWidget`, and set `setMovable(True)` to set free to move all tabs.
It works well to me, but I hope one more thing.
When tab move here to there, I want to get the SIGNAL the application to know.

`currentChanged(int)` SIGNAL doesn't fit to that.

If I reimplement the `QTabWidget`, what I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`tabMoved`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#tabMoved) signal of `QTabBar`. You can get the `QTabBar` used in `QTabWidget` with the [`tabBar()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#tabBar) method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As you mentioned, I could get the SIGNAL from QTabBar. Thanks again.